# program using named pipes crashed

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes

The program is about providing message between people created via FIFO by selected,

```
./a.out create name_of_person
```

The first condition `if( strcmp(argv[1], "create") == 0 )` works properly, but after that, after selecting `./a.out name1 name2 message` and while compiling the program hangs out (it's else condition).

How can I solve the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

 int i = 0;
 int fifo = -1;

 if( strcmp(argv[1], "create") == 0 ) { 
    int fifo = mkfifo(argv[2], 0666);

    if( ( fifo == -1) ) {
        perror("\n The problem occured. The program exited. \n");
        printf("error %d : %s \n", errno, strerror (errno));
    exit( 1 );
    }
 }

 else if( strcmp(argv[2], "history") == 0 ) {

  int process1 = fork();

  if( process1 == 0 ) {

    int process2 = fork();

    if( process2 == 0 )
     {
        char c;
        if (fifo == 0) {
        int FILE = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

        for(i=3; i<argc; i++) {
        read( FILE, argv[i], 1 );
        //while( ( Scanner = read( odFILE, &c, 1) ) > 0 )
        }

        close( FILE );
        }
    }
    kill();
 }
 }

 else 
 {

 if( (open(argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0777) == -1) || (open(argv[2], O_RDONLY, 0777) == -1) ) 
 {
  perror("The user does not exist."); 
  exit(1);
 }

 printf("< ");
 printf("%s", argv[1]);
 printf(" -> ");
 printf("%s", argv[2]);
 printf(" > : ");

 for(i=3; i<argc; i++) printf("%s", argv[i]);

 int process1 = fork();

 if( process1 == 0 ) {



int process2 = fork();

    if( process2 == 0 ) {
        int FILE = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
        write( FILE, argv[3], sizeof(argv[3]) );
        close( FILE );
    }

    kill();
 }
}

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: it would be much easier for everyone if you'd use english var names and comments and communicates (at least if you are posting code here), or at least be consistent about language, `kolejka` and `process1` ? come on!

Comment: Ok. Changes accepted. :)

Comment: First, look at the warnings your compiler is issuing while compiling that code, and try to correct your code so as most of them disappear. If some don't make sense, ask for guidance here.

Comment: But the program compiles properly. There are no errors. Its just crashing while selecting "./a.out name1 name2 message" (when the "else {" function is calling).

Comment: What exactly happens? Does your program hang or crash?

Comment: What is this function `kill`?

Comment: The program hangs.
I wanted to kill a process by using "kill".

Comment: Side note: `if( (open(argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0777) == -1)` leaks the opened file descriptor.

Comment: Why do you need to make 2 successive calls to `fork`?

Comment: @ Werner Henze, how to solve it? I have no idea...
@ didierc, I want to write to fifo using process in background.

Comment: `kill` normally takes 2 parameters on POSIX systems, I find it odd that your compiler doesn't say anything.

Comment: @didierc, so how can I kill the process I am inside?

Comment: `exit` (from "stdlib.h") or simply `return`.

Comment: @didierc, ok, i changed it, but the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man 3 mkfifo`:

> However, it has to be open at both ends simultaneously before you can proceed to do any input or output operations on it.  Opening a FIFO for reading normally blocks until some other process opens the same FIFO for writing, and  vice versa.

In your line

```
if( (open(argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0777) == -1) || (open(argv[2], O_RDONLY, 0777) == -1) )
```

you are opening both fifos for reading. Both opens will block until also a writer opens the fifo.
BTW, this if leaks both opened file descriptors.

Your later processing

```
int FILE = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
write( FILE, argv[3], sizeof(argv[3]) );
close( FILE );
```

has the same problem of blocking during open until a write opens the fifo. And there is another problem: you are opening the fifo for reading only but you are writing to it only.

You need to replace your `open` for checking if the files exists. Remove it - your later open will fail - or replace it with a `stat`. And you need to implement both sides of the messaging to test it, not only one side (or you need to run a shell command to write to or read from the fifo in parallel to your program to test it).

Other problems in your code:

1. You are not including the right header for kill - and you are calling kill without the needed parameters.
2. You are not including the right header for mkfifo.

You should consider enabling more warnings to see those problems in your code.

Comment: That's why I use double fork. I want the program works in background.
I gave the complete code.